# Firebase: Allowing users to create accounts for other users.

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

So I'm making this app for pharmacists and their patients. Pharmacists can manage their patient's data through the app - and most importantly sign up their patients to the app.

The ideal flow goes like this - at an appointment, pharmacist gets patient's email address. Pharmacists can then create a user account, either setting a password right then for the patient, or sending an email letting the user set one up.

Is there anyway for one user to create an account for another user within firebase?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

As long as its at a manageable rate as you could hit quota limitations.
The pharmacist can create a new password account with the email provided and some random password and then trigger the reset password flow. This will send a reset password link to the user.
You can then build a custom landing page for resetting the password where the user would take control and finish setting up their account.
Check the docs on building custom email action landing pages:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler